# Transactions encompassed by contract creation?

Tags: solidity, truffle, tokens, ganache

Given below is a simple token contract being migrated using truffle. What are the constituting transactions that make up this contract creation and why are these steps discrete? **Ignore the top transaction**

[image]

Comment: Contract creation happens in a single transaction. The screenshot you provided isn't enough for someone to tell you what the other transactions are about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those transactions are related to `Truffle`:

when migrating with truffle, truffle reads a value from it's, already deployed, contract called `migrations` if the value is less than a certain number(can call it network version) it invalidates the contract and redeploys it.

then truffle deploys your actual contract. so the extra transactions and calls are from truffle.

Note : truffle uses this method to keep track of the contract versions, so that it doesn't deploy the same contract( with no changes in its code) multiple times.